# Java new ArrayList clone inefficient

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm getting the value of an ArrayList inside an ArrayList containing integers from a HashMap. However, I need a new copy of this data; otherwise, I will be changing data inside of the HashMap, as it returns a reference.

To overcome this, I'm creating a new instance of the ArrayList Object for each inner ArrayList. Is there a better, more efficient way to achieve this result (potentially with a different data structure?), as it is taking a very long time to complete with a large amount of data.

```
// Example of how I am copying the data currently

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> calcRes = memo.get(n - i);
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> calc = new ArrayList<>();

for (ArrayList<Integer> item : calcRes) {
    calc.add(new ArrayList<>(item));
}
```

For a bit of context of why and how I am using this, I'm solving a problem to find all the possibilities to make stairs with N blocks.
Stairs have to descend each column by at least one. For example the stairs with six blocks would return [[5, 1], [4, 2], [3, 2, 1]]. However, for larger values N, such as 200, this takes much longer so I'm trying to cache the results inside the memo. I call the function the code above is in recursively to find more solutions. However, I don't want to change the object stored in the memo. This is because I add the previous item to the start. For example, with [3, 3] (which doesn't count as a solution), I would look at the 3 on the right and call the function I'm in again, which would give me [[2, 1]]. Then I would need to add on the 3 on the left of the original to add up to 6 blocks. This is why I am creating a new instance of the ArrayList; otherwise, the memo would be changed.

Comment: Have you looked at copy-on-write Array Lists? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: That would only work if it was *very unlikely* that the "copied" inner lists were changed.  Each time you modify a copy-on-write list, you make a fresh copy of the list's entire backing array.

Comment: Basically ... we don't have enough information about the OP's problem to recommend a better solution / more efficient data structure.  It depends on too many factors that have not been presented.

Comment: @StephenC sorry for not being descriptive enough. I have added more detail now to the question, which hopefully should help.

Comment: Generally speaking the solution sounds like it could be a directed acyclical graph: Each solution can point to another node that is itself a solution of another subset. So the node representing `[3, 2, 1]` would carry the step value `3` and point to the node representing `[2, 1]`.

Comment: What does your hashmap look like? You want to change the List's in calc, without modifying the lists in calcRes. Are you sure that `calc.add(new ArrayList<>(item))` is a bottle neck? As in does `calc.add(item)` significantly speed up the operation? I have had an issue with `List<Integer>` and replacing it with `int[]` made significant performance gains, but it might be completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @matt yes, when I just have `calc.add(item)` it does it near instantly with 100 items, however when creating the new ArrayList it doesn't even complete in 10 minutes.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks, I'll have a look at this!

Comment: Can you make a complete compilable example? Creating 100 new ArrayLists shouldn't take 10 minutes. Did you get an exception?

Comment: One observation: if you use a list of lists as a hashmap key, hashing is liable to be expensive.  The hash function computes the hashes of all leaf elements in the list-of-lists.

Comment: @matt It is not simply 100 Array Lists, i'm not sure the exact number for 100, but when n = 200 there would be 487067745

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense, I would agree you should be building a graph structure so you don't have to change the the backing lists. It seems like you're making a lot of redundant copies. With the N = 200 you're hitting around 1GB of data, just for storing the lists.